Brand-Specific `AndroidManifest.xml` Not Being Merged in .NET MAUI Project
I'm working on a personal project where I need to use different AndroidManifest.xml files for different brands of the app. Each brand has its own manifest file located in a separate directory. However, despite configuring the .csproj to include the correct AndroidManifest.xml for the active brand, the build process only includes the base AndroidManifest.xml, and the brand-specific manifest is not being merged.
Project Setup:

Base Manifest Location: Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
Brand-Specific Manifest Location: Stuff/Brand1/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
Development Environment: Visual Studio 2022, .NET MAUI

What I’ve Tried:

Several variations of modifying the .csproj file as such:
<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <AndroidManifest Include="Stuff/Brand1/Android/AndroidManifest.xml">
        <LogicalName>Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml</LogicalName>
    </AndroidManifest>
</ItemGroup>

OR
<ItemGroup Condition="$(cfg.Contains('-Brand1'))">
    <None Remove="Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <AndroidManifest Include="Stuff/Brand1/Android/AndroidManifest.xml">
        <LogicalName>Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml</LogicalName>
    </AndroidManifest>
</ItemGroup>

Conditionals do work in .csproj as I am using them for other brand-specific settings.

Clean and Rebuild: I’ve performed a clean build multiple times, but the brand-specific manifest is still not being merged.

Checked Merged Manifest: After the build, I checked the obj/Debug/android/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml, and it only contains the base manifest.

Build Output Logs: I reviewed the build logs but didn’t see any obvious errors or warnings related to the manifest merging process.


The Problem:
Despite these efforts, the brand-specific AndroidManifest.xml isn’t being picked up or merged during the build. As a result, 3rd party configurations, which are specific to the brand, are missing in the final build.
Questions:

How can I ensure that the brand-specific AndroidManifest.xml is correctly included and merged during the build process?
Is there something I might be missing in the .csproj configuration that could be causing this issue?
Are there any additional steps or settings in .NET MAUI that I need to configure to support brand-specific manifests?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help.
BONUS
Would also be nice to know if:
<meta-data
    android:value="${ApplicationId}.MYCLASS"/>

is valid syntax within the AndroidManifest.xml.

I'm having the same issue, did you ever manage to resolve?

@Ron Yes, I was able to resolve this. I will post the solution today

Thanks @KING, managed to resolve in the end too.


Add Android Manifests as so.



Have no Manifest present at Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml

Update .csproj file to set the manifest for chosen Build Configurations


<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android34.0|AnyCPU'">
    <AndroidManifest>Platforms\Android\Public\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>    
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='ReleaseE|net8.0-android34.0|AnyCPU'">  
 <AndroidManifest>Platforms\Android\Enterprise\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>     
</PropertyGroup>


This is technically a correct way to handle the situation.
What I was trying to achieve was the minimization of multiple Manifest files as only portions of the files were being changed.
I was eventually able to get the following working, allowing me to only have a single Manifest file
<meta-data
    android:value="${applicationId}.MYCLASS"/>```
